# how to add comment in delphi form

Tags: delphi

I want to add some comments the automatically generated form (dfm) files. In pas we can comment using // or {} but how to add comment in dfm?

Is it possible to add comment? I tried add comment at end of dfm but when i reopen comment gets deleted.

thanks or help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that is not possible. A DFM file is nothing but a representation of the object structure. Normally you shouldn't read nor write any DFM file directly (unless you know exactly what you do). Earlier versions of Delphi used the internal binary format for DFM files, which can still  be achieved by changing a setting. There is no place for comments in that, too.

**Update:**
You can still write your documentation right above the declaration of the control in the PAS file.

Comment: Delphi still supports storing DFM files in a binary format.  It is just less common to do so, typically because DFMs tend to be stored in VCS systems so text formats are usually used so they can be diff'ed when needed.

Answer (score 3):

Published component properties are written to the DFM file, and the IDE manages that entire process.  Any unsupported content in the DFM will be discarded the next time the IDE opens the form, which you have already observed.

**Workaround**: If you just want to add comments to a small number of components, you could easily write a component wrapper and add one new published property where you could add a comment through the property editor.  Kind of a hokey workaround, but doable...  The drawback is that your comments would be compiled into the EXE.

Comment: Along the same lines: put a component like a button or memo on the form and set its Visible property to False.  You would then embed your comment in the .Caption or .Lines property (respectively). As in James L's solution, the comment would ship with the program. And the component adds a bit of clutter to the form when viewing it in the IDE. (That could even be an advantage. For example, if you embed your comment in a memo, then you can read it right in the IDE.)

Answer (score 0):

Up until Delphi 7, there was a rudimentary design surface where you could put comments on. It was saved as a separate file. I forgot the name, and also if it was only for non-visual designers or also for the form/frame designer.

From Delphi 2005 and up, that is gone.

The easiest is to write a small non-visual component `TComment` that has a `Lines` property of type `TStrings` in which you store comments, and maybe even a `Component` property that can link to the target component for which the comment is.

Each DFM gets compiled into a binary version that is linked into your EXE (that's one of the reasons the IDE still supports binary DFM files; the other is backward compatibility).

That means that comments like those will also end up in your EXE.

Comment: *.ddp ?  IMHO it was D7-only.  Do not recall THAT kind of garbage in D5

Comment: Such a component, Strings Holder, is already in RxLib/JediVCL
But not only would it make to .EXE, it also is global. It is like commenting at unit's top. Such a comment can not be attached to particular data line in DFM.

Comment: @Arioch'The You are right, that was the Diagram Editor extension available in Delphi 6 and 7: http://filext.com/file-extension/DDP Thanks for the JediVCL/RxLib mentioning; it should not be hard to add a component reference property in there.